# How to thow an exception into a task?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

`asyncio.Task` only provides a method for throwing an empty `CancelledError` into the task. However, sometimes it might be desirable to have different types of interrupt. For example, similar to SIGINT, SIGTERM and SIGKILL, multiple levels of cancellation may allow a task to do a better cleanup.

`asyncio.Task` itself can be easily modified to provide such functionality. The question is, how to do it in a more elegant and efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

I asyncio was providing such functionality long time ago, but it was cut.

Now in documentation you can [read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object):

> asyncio.Task inherits from Future all of its APIs except
>   Future.set_result() and Future.set_exception().

And in asyncio [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L164) you can see:

```
def set_exception(self, exception):
    raise RuntimeError('Task does not support set_exception operation')
```

You can read discussion behind this decision in relevant [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4923) and [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue32363).

From how I understand stuff supporting `set_result`/`set_exception` spawns too many ways to shoot yourself in the foot, for example see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-tulip/-EcYtJXDvSo/mES8xjj0BAAJ) discussion.

Comment: I think that was something different. `set_exception` and `cancel` represent different direction of information flow. `set_exception` is for the producer to notify the consumer, while `cancel` is exactly the inverse. Throwing an exception into the task is some form of a consumer notifying the producer , so the proper way would be `cancel(reason=some_exception)`, instead of reusing `set_exception`. Either way, even when `set_exception` didn't raise a `RuntimeError`, it had no affect on wrapped coroutine.